# Firebase (Android Studio): atomically delete user and all his data from realtime and storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, firebase-storage

I have a user info in my **realtime firebase** database, but i have also a specific folder for that user in **storage firebase database**. How i can atomically delete **all** his data in such a way that **everything is eliminated or nothing**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to delete data atomically across multiple Firebase services. You will have to delete them one by one.

This means you will have to pick an order in which to delete things, and make sure any client code can deal with lingering partial data/files. Additionally, you'll want to run a periodic process to clean up such orphaned data/files.