# delete from firebase firestore and firebase storage Simultaneous

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on notes app and I want to make sure if the user deletes the note the image for that note will be deleted as well , and if any error happen he shouldn't delete any of them how can I achieve that

```
// this code is to delete the image that related to the document
await FirebaseStorage.instance
    .refFromURL(
    snapshot.data!.docs[index]['imageURL'])
    .delete();
// this code is to delete a document
await notesReference
    .doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id)
    .delete();
```

Comment: Your question needs more details. Edit it and paste code you try so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no way to run an atomic operation across multiple Firebase services like that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737730/firebase-android-studio-atomically-delete-user-and-all-his-data-from-realtime

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this example for deleting records from Firebase Firestore and Storage

Deleting a record from Firebase Firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection')
.doc('some_id') // <-- Doc ID to be deleted. 
.delete() // <-- Delete
.then((_) => print('Deleted'))
.catchError((error) => print('Delete failed: $error'));
```

deleting records from Firebase Storage
here you need to pass URL of an image

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete()
```

for more details you can follow this documents [Flutter Firebase](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/)

Comment: that will delete them separately, I want to make sure that he deleted both, and if he can't delete one of them, he shouldn't delete the other

Comment: @EsraaHamada Fairy will not allow him to delete one of the files ?

Comment: you can create a firebase function to delete both records at once. then call the firebase function from the app